# How to setImageResource?

Tags: java, android, imageview, baseadapter

I want to get ImageView from String to Int  at `picture.setImageResource( );` I use String to Integer Change, it doesn't show in GridView. How to get Image size and setImageView?

Menu.java

```
public class Menu {

private Integer id;
private String menuImage;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMenuImage() {
        return menuImage;
    }

    public void setMenuImage(String menuImage) {
        this.menuImage = menuImage;
    }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Menu> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>(); // from server
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MenuGridViewAdapter(Context context, List<Menu> menuList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.menuList = menuList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Menu getItem(int i) {
        return mItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);

        Item item = getItem(i);    
        picture.setImageResource( ); // 

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get the id of the respective image to use in setImageResource()

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/your_image", "id", "your_package_name");
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

and as for height and width you can set parameters like this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.imgLayout2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(340, 340);
    parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    parms.setMargins(20, 50, 20, 50);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Answer (score 0):

imageView.setImageResource() expects an image from Drawable, and that is an int, e.g.: R.drawable.sample
You may use picasso library instead of setImageResource. For that,

Add the following line to load add image into imageview.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(picture);
```

add this in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
       if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

       imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse("your url here")); // updated code
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
    };

}
```

Comment: hello, @Simranjeet Singh Images are come from Server inside List<Menu> getImage( ) are String NOT int, How to get from it?